# Write in sharepoint List from R

Tags: r, api, sharepoint

I am trying to write inside a sharepoint list from my R script but I keep getting this error :
*Error: node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow*

I am using the package sharepointr that I found in this github repository : https://github.com/LukasK13/sharepointr

I used the sp_WriteListData but it doesn't seem to work. I tried to execute the function step by step with its code, which can be found here : https://rdrr.io/github/LukasK13/sharepointr/src/R/sharepoint_list_post.R

The function always stops at the last step when I execute this line of code :
sp_request(con, request = request, verb = "POST", body = data).

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you show the error message and code you used?

Comment: The error message I get is : 
**Error: node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow**

and the code is the one written in this link : 
https://rdrr.io/github/LukasK13/sharepointr/src/R/sharepoint_list_post.R